# how to add log4j2 file multi maven project

Tags: java, maven, log4j2, multi-project

I am working on Multi Maven Project which has structure like below -

```
TestRepo (Maine Project)
    -APITests
    -Shared libraries
    -FrontendTests
```

Now Shared Libraries is common to both API Tests and Frontend Tests
I have added log4j for all the child projects, but however when i can api tests , it creates two log files one under api tests and anothe rone under shared libraries.

How can i merge two log files instead?

Comment: Why don't you add the log4j dependency in the parent project, so it will be inherited from the child projects?

Comment: When i add log4j properties to parent project the logger doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should manually configure where to save the log file. I think the following article is useful:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html